# Looking for an efficient audio amp circuit

Tags: amplifier, audio, heatsink, efficiency

It seems like all the circuits that I find are using outdated and inefficient technology that requires massive heat-sinks at anything beyond headphone levels. Is there any particular reason that there aren't any "efficient" amps that waste less power in the form of heat?

I have looked at the "classes" of amps, and this is a summary:

- class A amp - max (theoretical) efficiency of 50%
- class B amp - max (theoretical) efficiency of 78.5%
- class C amp - max is somewhat lower than class B, roughly 75%
- class D amp - theoretically can reach 100% efficiency
- class T amp - not sure as far as efficiency

I would like to see the circuit diagram (ideally with components, so I can build it) for a class D amp in the 50-200W range or so if such a thing exists, or if not, if someone could explain why they don't exist?

more details: I am hoping to put this in-wall with some speakers to drive them, thus heat (especially idle heat) is bad, and more of a concern than audiophile level audio. I would also greatly prefer packages that are easier to hand-solder (not surface mount please), or use in a breadboard. So far the best I have found is [this](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA8920C.pdf).

Comment: Step one: find a likely amp chip on a manufacturer's website (TI do some nice ones). Step two, download the datasheet.  Step three, read the datasheet, including the example circuit(s) they nearly all have. (I use the TPA3106D1 40W Mono amp a lot).

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle - any particular tips as for how to filter on "class D amps" or similar? I don't see any way of doing that on TI's website (although they do list it on the individual spec sheet).

Comment: Click "add/hide parameters" and add "Architecture" to the list of shown parameters.

Comment: I would suggest you go with an inefficient A or A/B push pull if you are just starting out.  You'll learn (what I think) is some good stuff getting 50% out of a class A.  Post some schematics, not numbers.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold - I need something that gives off less heat.. I was hoping something above 80% efficiency (but more would be better of course) - anyways, I was asking for schematics..

Comment: Class C makes no sense at all for a audio amp, since it exploits resonance at a particular frequency.

Comment: First, step up and learn how to solder coarse pitch surface mount.  It's not tricky - in fact it's a lot faster - you simply need to only solder one corner pin before you re-verify alignment.

Comment: You can buy class D amps for car use, or modular ones: http://www.dx.com/p/2-x-50w-dual-channel-stereo-d-t-class-hi-fi-amplifier-board-module-blue-216854#.VLvypy7X4lU - note that they still have some heat dissipation, so I'm not keen on the wall idea

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the amp? Class D may be efficient, but really scores low for fidelity (especially if you don´t get the filtering right). Class AB or G would be easier and give better fidelity.

Comment: Looking to mount it in-wall with a speaker where it will have limited ventilation.. I don't have that great hearing, and this isn't for the primary speakers, so fidelity is 2nd to efficiency.. What class G would you recommend? (I haven't seen any of those yet..)

Answer (score 0):

Is it worth building your own?    You can get a 200W + 200W Class D amp [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/161614958760?lpid=82&chn=ps) for $41.